# KendoUI chips are missing the border in local environment

Tags: html, css, angular, kendo-ui

I ran the test code from kendo in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkeh7e?file=app/app.component.ts) and it runs fine:

[image]

but when I run it on localhost, its missing all the styling of the chip:

[image]

**its appearing like a block, need help figuring out why this is happening**. I cant reproduce the error in stackblitz so far.

troubleshooting so far:

- I stopped my localhost and tried `npm i; npm start` as well.
- I compared all the dependencies in local vs stackblitz and they are in the package.json file

[image]

component.ts file

```js
import { Component,  ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { ChipRemoveEvent } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';
import { AutoCompleteComponent } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';

@Component({
  selector: 'sentryx-email-chips',
  templateUrl: './email-chips.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: ['./email-chips.component.scss']
})
export class EmailChipsComponent {
  @ViewChild("contactslist") public list: AutoCompleteComponent;

  public contacts: Array<{ label: string; iconClass: string }> = [
    { label: "Pedro Afonso", iconClass: "k-chip-avatar" },
    { label: "Maria Shore", iconClass: "k-chip-avatar" },
    { label: "Thomas Hardy", iconClass: "k-chip-avatar" },
    { label: "Christina Berg", iconClass: "k-chip-avatar" },
    { label: "Paula Wilson", iconClass: "k-chip-avatar" }
  ];

  public selectedContacts: Array<any> = [this.contacts[1]];

  public valueChange(contact: string): void {
    console.log(contact);
    if (contact === "") {
      return;
    }

    this.selectedContacts.push({
      label: contact,
      class: `custom-style`
    });

    // const contactData = this.contacts.find(c => c.label === contact);

    // if (!this.selectedContacts.includes(contactData)) {
    //   this.selectedContacts.push(contactData);
    // } else {
    //   this.selectedContacts.push({
    //     label: contact,
    //     iconClass: "k-chip-avatar paula"
    //   });
    // }

    this.list.reset();
  }

  public onRemove(e: ChipRemoveEvent): void {
    console.log("Remove event arguments: ", e);
    const index = this.selectedContacts
      .map(c => c.label)
      .indexOf(e.sender.label);
    this.selectedContacts.splice(index, 1);
  }

}
```

HTML:

```html
<kendo-chip *ngFor="let contact of selectedContacts" [class]="contact.class" [label]="contact.label" [removable]="true"
  [iconClass]="contact.iconClass" (remove)="onRemove($event)">
</kendo-chip>
<div class="example">
  <kendo-autocomplete #contactslist [data]="contacts" class="contacts" valueField="label"
    [kendoDropDownFilter]="{ operator: 'contains' }" [filterable]="true" placeholder="To: Email Adress*"
    (valueChange)="valueChange($event)">
  </kendo-autocomplete>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.k-chip {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .k-block {
    min-height: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .k-textarea {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 145px;
  }
  .contacts {
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 30px 0;
  }
  .contacts.k-state-focused {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  }

  .custom-style {
    color: #6200ee;
    background-color: #f3ebfe;
    border-color: #6200ee;
  }
```

**UPDATE**

Other kendo components work fine. like the kendo dropdown above. Also tested the kendo button and it works fine too
`<button kendoButton >Browse</button>`

[image]

Comment: Have you included the Kendo CSS file, and how. Do you have other Kendo controls on the page with the same issue?

Comment: I updated the question with the details you're asking. but all the other kendo components are styled properly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the style sheets were being imported in the the index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-theme-default@latest/dist/all.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-theme-default@latest/dist/all.css"></link>
```

These styles were missing from the angular application even though kendo chips were being imported from the module.

need to go to `style.css` for the app and add the line:

```js
@import "~@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/scss/chip";
```

I also had to go into node_modules to the progress package and the chip in there to test.